# Is it possible to sort records based on date in this format(May 31 2019 11:56PM) saved in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, database, sorting

[image]

I want to sort all my record in desc order of Time.Please help me in creating query.

Comment: Don't tell me your Time column is `VARCHAR`.

Comment: What @Eric said - for the love of all you hold holy change `Time` to a `DateTime` column.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...storing datetime values as strings is a losing proposition. Fortunately your strings (at least the ones posted) can be converted to a datetime.

You could use try_convert like this. But please realize the performance here is going to be pretty bad. Ideally you should store your data as datetime, then this is trivial. You might want to take a peek at this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

```
order by try_convert(datetime, [Time])
```

Comment: @DebendraDash You're not new. SO works because people ask questions that get answered so that others with the same questions can find answers. Please considering doing your part and marking answers.